# Laravel in docker - browserSync setup problems

Tags: laravel, docker, webpack

I'm struggling for a few hours now and cannot proprly set webpack-mix browserSync functionality for docker development enviroment.

I'd be glad to get some help!

Thanks in advace.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
```

services:
app:
build:
context: .
dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
image: vokl
container_name: vokl-app
ports:
- 80:80
- 3000:3000
- 3001:3001
volumes:
- ./:/var/www/html
networks:
- vokl
depends_on:
- mysql
mysql:
image: 'mariadb:latest'
container_name: vokl-db
restart: unless-stopped
ports:
- 3306:3306
environment:
MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
volumes:
- ./.docker/dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
networks:
- vokl
phpmyadmin:
image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
container_name: vokl-phpmyadmin
environment:
- PMA_HOST=mysql
- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
- MYSQL_USER=root
- MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
depends_on:
- mysql
ports:
- 8765:80
networks:
- vokl
networks:
vokl:
driver: bridge

webpack-mix:

mix.browserSync({
host: 'vokl-app.test',
proxy: 'app',
notify: false,
open: 'external'
});